# Connecting to signals sent by specific senders do not work as expected

Tags: django, django-signals

I have models strucute as below

```
class WalletTransactions(models.Model):
     ...
     fields here    
     ...

class WalletBalance(models.Model):
     ...
     fields here    
     ...
```

Signal handler like below

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=WalletTransactions)
def update_balance(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    print instance.payment_type #field in model
```

And finally registration

```
post_save.connect(update_balance, dispatch_uid=uuid.uuid4())
```

Now I am expecting `update_balance` to be called only when `save` on `WalletTransaction` is called as per [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/signals/#connecting-to-signals-sent-by-specific-senders).

But when I am trying to login to my application, the `update_balance` is being called when `save` on   `Session` is called throwing following error.

> AttributeError at /login/
>   'Session' object has no attribute 'payment_type'

What could be the mistake here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are connecting you callback function **twice**.
You can either connect the signal with `@receiver` **or** with `post_save.connect`.

See here for more information: 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/signals/#connecting-receiver-functions

Additionally, you didn't specify a `sender` in `post_save.connect()`. So basically you connect the callback to the save method of **every** object.

To make it work simply remove this line:

```
post_save.connect(update_balance, dispatch_uid=uuid.uuid4())
```

Comment: Yes, You are right, and that line is overriding the decorator.